# Drawing a 2D Heptagon OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Having trouble drawing a heptagon in my OpenGL program. I want to draw a heptagon within a rectangle, so far I can draw the red rectangle but the heptagon isn't showing up.

I don't think I need to convert to degrees unless I wanted to rotate it right? Here is my code:

```
void CChildView::OnGLDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    int width, height;
    GetSize(width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, // left
        1.0, // right
        0.0, // bottom
        GLdouble(height) / GLdouble(width), // top
        1.0, // near
        -1.0); // far

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3d(1., 0., 0.);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);    // Rectangle
    glVertex2d(0.25, 0.25);
    glVertex2d(0.75, 0.25);
    glVertex2d(0.75, 0.75);
    glVertex2d(0.25, 0.75);
    glEnd();

    glColor3d(1., 1., 1.);

    int numPoints = 7; // Heptagon
    double x, y;
    double radius = 0;
    double centerx = 0;
    double centery = 0;

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
    {
        x = centerx + radius * sin(2.0*M_PI*i / numPoints);
        y = centery + radius * cos(2.0*M_PI*i / numPoints);

        glVertex2d(x, y);

    }
    glEnd();

    glColor3d(0., 1., 0.);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2d(m_linefmx, m_linefmx);
    glVertex2d(m_linetox, m_linetoy);
    glEnd();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the rectangle to see if anything shows up? Have you debugged to see that your calculated coordinates are correct? Btw usually `sin` is for `y` and `cos` is for `x`.

Comment: Just noticed that your `radius` is set to 0 and not modified later - so all points will probably be calculated as (0,0)

Comment: Yes, the radius was the issue. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Good to hear. There's no problem with the question, I would keep it. I'll write my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `radius` is initialized to 0 and never changed, so all points are calculated as (0,0).